# Is it possible to modify a method passed to class as parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering can I modify method passed as parameter to class?

For example let's say that I have created class `Column` in which I will create column, add `EventListener` on this column with callback recived as parameter. But I will also want to modify this method by adding special line which will save is `column` was clicked or unclicked.

```
class TableColumn {

    column = document.createElement('th');
    clickState = false;

    constructor(callback) {
        this.column.textContent = 'sort ascending / descending';
        this.column.addEventListener('click', callback);
    }

}
```

I know that I can achieve this by manipulating element attribute for example :

```
colum.setAttribute('was-sorted', 'false');
```

Or by toggling class :

```
column.classList.toggle('sorted');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you can achieve what you want by prepending the call to the `callback` with the behaviour you desire:

```
constructor(callback) {
    this.column.textContent = 'sort ascending / descending';
    this.column.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        // Your desired code here

        // Call the callback
        callback(ev);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the callback function and pass it in 'addEventListener' function.

```
class TableColumn {

    column = document.createElement('th');
    clickState = false;

    constructor(callback) {
        this.column.textContent = 'sort ascending / descending';
        this.column.addEventListener('click', (...args) => {
            // your code here
            callback(...args);
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying a function, a typical approach would be to create a unique instance of that function, something like:

```
class TableColumn {

    column = document.createElement('th');
    clickState = false;

    constructor(callback, params) {
        let innerCallback = (params) => callback(params);

        this.column.textContent = 'sort ascending / descending';
        this.column.addEventListener('click', innerCallback);
    }

}
```

**Edit:** *the other two answers posted are essentially functionally the same as this, and it depends on how you prefer to format your code. But ultimately, all three answers are the same. Personally, I prefer to use named functions so that if you added another eventHandlers, you don't need to duplicate any code - you can just re-use the same innerCallback callback*

**Edit 2**: *To show how to expand the `innerCallback` function, see below.*

```
class TableColumn {

    column = document.createElement('th');
    clickState = false;

    constructor(callback, params) {
        let innerCallback = (params) => {
            /* Do stuff here*/

            callback(params)
        };

        this.column.textContent = 'sort ascending / descending';
        this.column.addEventListener('click', innerCallback);
    }

}
```

Comment: ye but it will not change anything i will still not be able to change ```clickState``` prop of this class in this callback function

Comment: You can expand the innerCallback the same as with the other two answers. For example, have `let innerCallback = (params) => { /* do stuff here */ callback(params); }` so functionally it is the same. Just named. Edited answer to demonstrate

Comment: yes but before you edited yor answer it was like you create arrow function with params which are send to this class and than you are using callback prop recived also as param and send this param to this callback which is not modyfting this this callback so it is not an answer on my question

Comment: If you check my most recent edit, I have elaborated. Functionally, this is exactly the same as the accepted answer. The only difference is my answer uses a named function, whilst the accepted answer uses an anonymous function.